# JQuery can't get input value from dynamically created field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Receiving  value from static field when keyup based on input field class(.inputclass) method, but once add field dynamically its not get the value.

Below the sample code, Please help.

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".inputclass").keyup(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<form>
<table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="inputclass" /></td>
  </tr>
  <script>
 var counter =1;
 $(function(){
  $('#addNew').click(function(){
   counter += 1;
   $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td>Field ' + counter + '</td><td><input type="text" class="inputclass"/></td></tr>');
  });
 });
</script>
</table><br/>
<input type="button" id="addNew" value=" &plusmn; Add New Field"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `$(function(){` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`. Use only once.

Comment: `$(function(){})` is not shorthand for `$(document).ready`. its Immediately-invoked function expression ([IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', '.inputclass', function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<form>
<table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="inputclass" /></td>
  </tr>
  <script>
 var counter =1;
 $(function(){
  $('#addNew').click(function(){
   counter += 1;
   $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td>Field ' + counter + '</td><td><input type="text" class="inputclass"/></td></tr>');
  });
 });
</script>
</table><br/>
<input type="button" id="addNew" value=" &plusmn; Add New Field"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks SilverSurfer for your response, its working. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is because when you assigned the event handler, it only assigned to the existing elements at the time.

[Delegate to the document](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputclass', function(){
   alert($(this).val())
});
```

When you delegate to a parent or the document, you are using the event that bubbles up and so it doesn't matter if there are dynamic elements.

Comment: Thank you for your Swift response  MrCode,  I checked  and Its working perfectly.  thanks once again. _/\_